# Dúvida sobre layout estendido do Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

Minha dúvida é muito extensa e acredito que com um vídeo no Youtube fica mais fácil para entender meu problema:

[Meu problema](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M0R5LU5C8Xo)

Esse é meu repositório sem as alterações:

[Meu repositório](https://github.com/wladyband/vuerender/tree/master/frondend/src)

Imagem do erro;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Base.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-header>
      <v-toolbar>
        <v-nav-icon @click.native="toggleDrawer" />
        <v-toolbar-title>Music DB</v-toolbar-title>
        <v-toolbar-actions>
          <v-toolbar-action>
            <v-icon>exit_to_app</v-icon>
          </v-toolbar-action>
        </v-toolbar-actions>
      </v-toolbar>
      <transition name="slide-left">
        <v-drawer v-if="drawerActive">
          <v-drawer-header>
            <v-nav-icon
              variant="green"
              @click.native="toggleDrawer"
            />
            <v-drawer-title>Music DB</v-drawer-title>
          </v-drawer-header>
          <v-drawer-body>
            <v-navigation>
              <v-navigation-item>
                <v-navigation-link :route="{ name: 'artists.index' }">
                  <v-navigation-content>Artists</v-navigation-content>
                </v-navigation-link>
                <v-navigation-link :route="{ name: 'albums.index' }">
                  <v-navigation-content>Albums</v-navigation-content>
                </v-navigation-link>
                <v-navigation-link :route="{ name: 'songs.index' }">
                  <v-navigation-content>Songs</v-navigation-content>
                </v-navigation-link>
              </v-navigation-item>
            </v-navigation>
          </v-drawer-body>
          <v-drawer-footer>For educational purposes only</v-drawer-footer>
        </v-drawer>
      </transition>
    </v-header>
    <v-content>
      <!-- The content of the page will be placed here -->
      <slot></slot>
    </v-content>
    <transition name="fade">
      <v-overlay
        v-show="drawerActive"
        @click.native="hideDrawer"
      />
    </transition>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    /**
     * The name of the layout.
     */
    name: 'base-layout',

    data() {
      return {
        drawerActive: false,
      };
    },

    /**
     * The methods which the layout can use.
     */
    methods: {
      /**
       * Method used to hide the drawer.
       */
      hideDrawer() {
        this.drawerActive = false;
      },

      /**
       * Method used to toggle the drawer.
       */
      toggleDrawer() {
        this.drawerActive = !this.drawerActive;
      },
    },
  };
</script>
```

pagina principal

```
<template>
  <v-layout>
    <v-grid variant="container">
      <v-row variant="xs-center">
        <v-col :variants="['xs-9', 'md-4', 'lg-3']">
          <v-card>
            <v-card-body>
              <v-form @submit.prevent.native="setQuery(query)">
                <v-input-group>
                  <v-icon variant="signifier">search</v-icon>
                  <v-text-field
                    variant="with-signifier"
                    v-model="query"
                    placeholder="Find artist"
                  />
                </v-input-group>
              </v-form>
            </v-card-body>
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
        <v-col :variants="['xs-3', 'md-4', 'lg-3', 'md-offset-4', 'lg-offset-6']">
          <v-button
            variant="circle"
            class="pull-right"
            @click.native="redirectToCreatePage"
          >
            <v-icon>add</v-icon>
          </v-button>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
      <v-row>
        <v-col variant="sm">
          <v-table>
            <v-table-header>
              <v-table-row>
                <v-table-head>Name</v-table-head>
                <v-table-head>Birthday</v-table-head>
              </v-table-row>
            </v-table-header>
            <v-table-body>
              <v-table-row
                v-for="artist in artist.all"
                :key="artist"
                variant="body"
              >
                <v-table-cell>
                  <router-link :to="getArtistRoute(artist.id)">{{ artist.fullName }}</router-link>
                </v-table-cell>
                <v-table-cell>{{ artist.birthday }}</v-table-cell>
              </v-table-row>
              <v-table-row v-if="artist.all.length === 0">
                <v-table-cell colspan="3">Artists not found...</v-table-cell>
              </v-table-row>
            </v-table-body>
          </v-table>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
      <v-row>
        <v-col variant="xs-justify">
          <v-card variant="inline">
            <v-card-body>
              <v-pagination
                :pagination="artist.pagination"
                :switch-page-function="setPage"
                variant="small"
              />
            </v-card-body>
          </v-card>
          <v-card variant="inline">
            <v-card-body>
              <v-select
                v-model="artist.pagination.limit"
                :items="pageNumbers"
              />
            </v-card-body>
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-grid>
  </v-layout>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    /**
     * The name of the layout.
     */
    name: 'artist-index',

    data() {
      return {
        artist: {
          all: [],
          pagination: {
            totalCount: 0,
            totalPages: 0,
            currentPage: 1,
            limit: 5,
          },
        },
        drawerActive: false,
        query: null,
        pageNumbers: [
          5,
          10,
          15,
        ],
      };
    },

    /**
     * The methods which the layout can use.
     */
    methods: {
      /**
       * Method used to hide the drawer.
       */
      hideDrawer() {
        this.drawerActive = false;
      },

      /**
       * Method used to toggle the drawer.
       */
      toggleDrawer() {
        this.drawerActive = !this.drawerActive;
      },

      /**
       * Method used to get the artist route.
       *
       * @param {Number} id The artist identifier.
       *
       * @returns {Object} The artist route.
       */
      getArtistRoute() {
        // todo
      },

      /**
       * Method used to redirect the user to the artist create page.
       */
      redirectToCreatePage() {
        // todo
      },

      /**
       * Method used to go to a different page.
       *
       * @param {Number} page The page number.
       */
      setPage() {
        // todo
      },

      /**
       * Method used to set the limit of the items being displayed.
       *
       * @param {Number} limit The limit of items being displayed.
       */
      setLimit() {
        // todo
      },

      /**
       * Method used to set the query of the search bar.
       * The results will be debounced using the lodash debounce method.
       */
      setQuery() {
        // todo
      },
    },

    /**
     * Available watchers for this page.
     */
    watch: {
      query(query) {
        this.setQuery(query);
      },
    },

    components: {
      VLayout: require('@/layouts/base'),
    },
  };
</script>
```

Comment: Tecnologia super nova? por favor adicione o maximo de conteudo aqui.

Comment: Se o problema é grande assim seria melhor quebrar ele em pedaços (e perguntas) menores, fica mais objetivo para resolver.

Comment: Eu já fiz 4 tentativas de postagem sobre o mesmo assunto, e qual é a dificuldade? 1º as pessoas não conseguem entender minha dúvida. 2º eu posto e ninguém responde, eu não sei mais como fazer, o vídeo é um grito de desespero, e até agora o que as pessoas tem feito em relação a essa minha dúvida é fazendo criticas ou não conseguem me ajudar.

Comment: acredito, essa minha dúvida é um problema muito simples, se vocês puderem me ajuda eu imploro para assistir o vídeo.

Comment: acabei de fazer a alteração.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bem o que você que fazer é criar rotas na sua aplicação. Isso é bem fácil de fazer inclusive você já está usando.

1º o que é `v-layout`? Nada mais do que o nome que você deu para o componente base.
você vez isso em:

```js
components: {
  'v-layout': require('@/layouts/base')
}
```

Você pode aprender mais sobre como os componentes funcionam aqui: https://br.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html

#### Respondendo a sua pergunta

Você já esta usando a lib necessária pra criar rotas na sua aplicação que é a: https://router.vuejs.org

(Você pode aprender mas sobre o que falarei neste link https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html#nested-routes)

Você tem que criar um componente que tenha o header e o menu e dentro dele então você deve colocar um componente que var renderizar outro componente. O nome desse componente é `<router-view></router-view>` e ele tem que ficar a onde estaria o seu conteúdo.

Feito isso você tem que configurar as rotas para aparecerem dentro desse componente base (o que tem o header e o menu).
pra isso você tem que edita o arquivo `src/routes/index.js`

ele deve ficar mais ou menos assim:

```js
export default [
  {
    path: '/',
    redirect: '/artists',
    component: resolve => require(['@/layouts/base.vue'], resolve),
    children: [
      {
        path: '/albums',
        name: 'albums.index',
        component: resolve => require(['@/pages/albums/index.vue'], resolve),
      },
      // demais rota da sua aplicação
  }
]
```

#### Vou mandar um pull request no seu repositório.